# MGet on file without extension

Tags: ftp

In FTP, when I `mget *`, it only gets file with extension `*.xxx` and ignores those files without any extension, e.g. file name `ACC001`.

How can I get those files without extension?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find you need to set a `site` option somewhere (or use `quote` to send a specific low-level command to the FTP server - use `quote help` for details). The `mget` command is typically implemented at the lower level as a `NLST` (name list) followed by a series of `RETR` (retrieve) operations.

Since `NLST` is a command to the server to give you a list of names, it's probably the server that's delivering only those files with an extension.

Without knowing the server you're connecting to, (Windows, UNIX, z/OS, ...), it's a little hard to give further information.