# ftp command mget - get file without extension but avoid conflicting file with extension

Tags: ftp, terminal, sftp

***Note:*** This is not a duplicate of [2597394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597394/mget-on-file-without-extension).

I have an FTP server (Unix or Linux) with a folder that contains the following files *(for example)*:

- **filename.txt**
- **filename.txt.abc**
- **filename**

When I issue `mget file*` command to `ftp` or `sftp`, I can fetch all three files. What I need to do is to fetch only the **filename** file (the one without any extension).

I tried `grep` and `|` but these aren't recognized by the `ftp` or `sftp` commands' prompt. I also tried `--exclude` but the mget here doesn't even support any options. The man page is something like [this](http://ss64.com/nt/ftp.html).

How do I solve this problem? I cannot specify the exact filename as it's not known. It must be a wild card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not an exact solution to the original problem, I created a workaround as follows. The workaround will still get all the three files, but it will then use the `rm` shell command to delete the files with extensions.

```
mget   file*
!rm -f file*.*
```

Only the file without extension will remain after the operation is completed. Note that `!` tells `ftp` or `sftp` to execute what's on its right using the local shell. A potential problem with this workaround is the inadvertent deletion of existing local files.